# display:table killing me in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-tables

I want to create horizontally-aligned table cells [like the ones on this page](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/wrongWithIE/?chapter=Table+Styles).

I've followed the instructions, and I've even copied the css and markup verbatim, but no matter what I do IE 8 renders my table cells as blocks (stacked on top of each other instead of aligned next to each other).

css:

```
<style type="text/css">

body.TableStyles {
    display: inline-table;
    border-spacing: 4px;
}

div.maketable p {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #cdf;
    padding: 4px;
}

</style>
```

markup:

```
<body class="TableStyles">
<div class="maketable">
        <p>< prev</p>

        <p>next ></p>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should Replace your body tag with this one, it will work definitely !

```
<body class="TableStyles">
<div class="maketable">
        <table>
        <tr>
         <td>
           <p>< prev 
           </p>
         </td>
         <td>
         <p>next >
         </p>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not well formed. The < and > before and after previous and next need to be escaped as `&lt;` and `&gt;` , respectively. This is probably forcing the browser into some quirks mode where it isn't CSS conform

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but removing those characters altogether has no effect.

Comment: ok, does your html have a valid xhtml doctype declaration? see http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html for explanation

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this, why not use `<ul><li>` to achieve the effect?